# How to represent two gates addition on Qiskit composer. we can do tensor product and multiplication but how to do Addition

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, ibm-q-experience, superconducting-quantum-computing

How to represent two gates addition on Qiskit composer we can do it in python code by using qiskit library but I would like to visually see how addition of two operators look like in composer.

I am currently working on VQLS Algorithm and we have to decompose given matrix into linear combination of unitary matrices. I want to see that in Qiskit composer.

Thanks

Comment: Would you consider writing it in code and using decomposition there before printing the circuit?

Comment: Can you give some sample code for addition operator.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but I assume you mean how to combine two operators into one? You can use `compose` for that: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Operator.compose.html What is more, you can decompose any operator (as long as it's an actual quantum operator) into a series of basic operators using either `decompose` https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.decompose.html or transpiler https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/transpiler.html

Comment: I mean when I decompose a non unitary matrix into series pauli base matrices like    ( A = aX + bY + cZ ) where X,Y,Z are pauli basis and I want to visually show my matrices decomposition on composer and if I keep my operators side by side it will do multiplication..My question is How to show it on composer?  should i create a custom gate or How ? and one more question is how to show my coefficient values along with my operator ? any QISKIT Composer snip will help.. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean IBM Quantum composer, it allows OpenQASM 2.0 as input. You could synthesises your circuit and them exported as OpenQASM 2.0:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 1, 0],
          [1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0]]
          
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.unitary(matrix, [0, 1])
circuit.decompose().qasm(filename='my_circuit.qasm')
```

Then, take `my_circuit.qasm` and import it in IBM Quantum Composer:
[image: screenshot of IBM Quantum Composer]